# How to Invalidate Metadata, Refresh, and Insert in Impala

Tags: hadoop, impala

I'm getting metadata errors when trying to load (via insert) an HDFS table with Impala.

```
INVALIDATE METADATA        s.event_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t.target_table;
INVALIDATE METADATA        t.target_table;
REFRESH                    t.target_table;
TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS   t.target_table;

INSERT INTO TABLE
    t.target_table
SELECT * 
FROM s.event_table;
```

> ERROR: AnalysisException: Failed to load metadata for table:
>   's.event_table'
>
> CAUSED BY: TableLoadingException: Failed
>   to load metadata for table: s.event_table.
>
> Running 'invalidate metadata s.event_table' may resolve this
>   problem.
>
> CAUSED BY: MetaException: Exception thrown when executing query

Running `INVALIDATE METADATA...` didn't work, as you can see.

Is this the appropriate usage and ordering of `INVALIDATE METADATA` , `REFRESH`, `[TRUNCATE]`, `[INSERT]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding another `REFRESH s.event_table` after `INVALIDATE METADATA s.event_table` *seems to have* worked.

Would still appreciate seeing another answer/comment on what this usage and ordering accomplishes, and if it is appropriate.

EDIT: This did not work on re-run. Now I get the same error on `TRUNCATE`